# base64 decode function: SIGSEGV, , Segmentation fault

Tags: c

This is a function decode the base64. SIGSEGV(sometimes it is SIGABORT) occurs at the line of the malloc called. It almost drive me crazy! Thanks in advance.

```
static char base64_table[255] = {'\0'};

static void base64_tableinit()
{
   int i,j;
   bzero(base64_table,255);
   for(j=0,i='A';i<='Z';i++) 
       base64_table[i]=j++;
   for(i='a';i<='z';i++)
       base64_table[i]=j++;
   for(i='0';i<='9';i++)
       base64_table[i]=j++;

   base64_table['+']=j++;
   base64_table['/']=j++;
   base64_table['=']=j;
}    
char *decode(const char *cptr,char **rptr)
{
    if(cptr==NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "The input string is NULL!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int len = strlen(cptr);
    if(len%4 != 0)  
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "The input string length is not 4X!\n");
        exit(1);
     }

     base64_tableinit();
     int clen=len/4;

#ifdef DEBUG
    /// printf ("The length of string len = %d\n",len);
    /// printf ("The length of string clen = %d\n",clen);
#endif
    char* res = NULL;
    /// Error: below, SIGSEGV
    if((res=(char *)malloc((len-clen + 1) * sizeof(char)))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Can't malloc enough space in decode!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(*rptr=res; clen>0; clen--)
    {
        *res = base64_table[(int)*cptr++]<<2 ;              /* Use the 1th char(6) */
        *res++|= base64_table[(int)*cptr]>>4 ;               /* Use the 2th char(2) */ /// Construct the first char 

        *res = base64_table[(int)*cptr++]<<4 ;              /* Use the 2th char(4) */
        *res++ |= base64_table[(int)*cptr]>>2 ;             /* Use the 3th char(4) */  /// Construct the second char 


        *res = base64_table[(int)*cptr++]<<6;               /* Use the 3th char(2) */
        *res++ |= base64_table[(int)*cptr++]&0x3f;          /* Use the 4th char(6) */  /// Construct the third char 

    }
    *(res+len-clen) = '\0';

    return *rptr;
}
```

The backtrace of gdb.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0xb71a2b70 (LWP 5432)]
0xb7d450a6 in _int_malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
0  0xb7d450a6 in _int_malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
1  0xb7d4746c in malloc () from /lib/libc.so.6
2  0x0804b04c in decode (
cptr=0x806dce8  "PGRpdiBzdHlsZT0ibGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6MS43O2NvbG9yOiMwMDAwMDA7Zm9udC1zaXplOjE0cHg7Zm9udC1mYW1pbHk6YXJpYWwiPuato+W4uCA8YnI+PC9kaXY+PGJyPjxicj48c3BhbiB0aXRsZT0ibmV0ZWFzZWZvb3RlciI+PHNwYW4gaWQ9Im5ldGVhc2VfbWFp"..., rptr=0xb71a1fa8) at base64.c:78
3  0x0804d5af in email_decode (email_old=0xb71a1ffc, email_new=0xb71a1d50) at email_handle.c:421
4  0x0804a9c2 in PacketAnalyze () at packet_analyze.c:800
5  0xb7fa1cf2 in start_thread () from /lib/libpthread.so.0
6  0xb7da584e in clone () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: @sidyll Sorry for not clear, edited just now

Comment: is this minimal sample able to reproduce the problem? if not, can you provide one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
*(res+len-clen) = '\0';
```

seems wrong, since you've already incremented `res` all through the loop, it should probably just be

```
*res = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

A segmentation fault in `malloc` is a fairly sure sign that either some wild memory corruption occurs or that someone `free`s a pointer to non-dynamically-allocated memory. Both errors did not necessarily happen in the code you show or the code that triggers the `SIGSEGV`.
However, both errors are often detected by `valgrind`.

Comment: Does it mean that the error may occur other place, but the gcc reports the error at where the memory is allocated?

Comment: @LouXiou: `gcc` reports no error here. `gcc` finished its work when it finished compiling, it has nothing to do with running the program. The program crashes, it has broken memory allocation, and the broken allocation is probably at a wholly different place in the code.

Comment: Sorry.. i mean the backtrace message reported by gdb.